# Error Installing flask-mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am running Windows 10 and Python 3.6.3 . I am trying to install flask-mysqldb
using

```
pip install flask-mysqldb.
```

It fails with the following:

> Command "c:\users...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\..~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5lp__7r6\mysqlclient\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users...~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zvpyshav\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users...~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5lp__7r6\mysqlclient\

I have tried to install the build tools for Visual Studio, but this doesn't seem to help.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Try typing `pip install Flask-MySQL`.If it don't works then try installing with [`.whl file`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/7a/ee1b74a211c3da66383eb07d0221cee6b0c3490e5003b797e66b6eaf9592/Flask_MySQL-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It does install but it does not help as I need to use MySQL from the mysqldb module.

Answer (score 0):

**On windows computers, mysql connector is a better alternative.**

Install it using:

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

I hope that solves your problem.